# IronPython mapping to managed value class

Tags: ironpython

I am trying to use IronPython to do some automation in some CAD software MicroStation through a COM Interop DLL. When I try to get a 'custom type' from an object it throws me ValueErrors. My quick code is below:

```
import sys, clr, System, os
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Bentley\\MicroStation V8i (SELECTseries)\\MicroStation\\assemblies")
clr.AddReferenceToFile("bentley.interop.microstationdgn.dll")

from Bentley.Interop.MicroStationDGN import Application, Point2d, Point3d, TextElement

t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MicroStationDGN.Application")
ms = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t)

elem = ms.ActiveDesignFile.GetElementByID64(509)
coord = elem.Origin
```

ValueError: The specified record cannot be mapped to a managed value class.

elem.Origin should give me a Point3d object...

However, if I do this:

```
>>> test = Point3d()
>>> Point3d.X.SetValue(test, 1)
>>> Point3d.Y.SetValue(test, 1)
>>> elem.Origin = test
>>> elem.Rewrite()
```

I am able to 'set' the Origin value of the element. (and I can verify in the CAD software that the origin of the element has moved).

I am sure I am missing some simple COM/IronPython thing, but I have looked over the docs and nothing jumps out at me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I read this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811445

I had to register the types first! So I executed this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regasm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ben
tley\MicroStation V8i (SELECTseries)\MicroStation\assemblies\bentley.interop.mic
rostationdgn.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>
```

Now:

```
>>> elem.Origin
<Bentley.Interop.MicroStationDGN.Point3d object at 0x000000000000002E [Bentley.Interop.MicroStationDGN.Point3d]>
>>> elem.Origin.X
1.0
```

Awesome.